# using pandas dataframe to create matplotlib bar chart

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pyspark, bar-chart

This is an example of how my pandasDF dataframe look like. This is a movie dataset. The count represent how each movie title represent 1.

```
| yearOfRelease |count|
| 1989          | 1   |
| 1990          | 1   |
| 1991          | 1   |
| 1992          | 1   |
| 1993          | 1   |
```

Previously my dataframe is a spark dataframe but i convert it to a pandas dataframe

```
pandasDF = movies_DF.toPandas()
pandasDF.head()
```

This is the plot i have right now.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jduJG.png]

I am trying to achieve a plot that look like this.

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsRT.png)]

This is my code:

```
x = list(pandasDF[pandasDF['yearOfRelease'] >= '1990']['yearOfRelease'])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
pd.value_counts(x).plot.bar(title="number of movies by year of release ")


plt.xlabel("yearOfRelease")
plt.ylabel("numOfMovies")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your `yearOfRelease` is string, convert them to integers. Also `pd.value_counts(x, sort=False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort your values by index (yearOfRelease):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sr = pandasDF.loc[pandasDF['yearOfRelease'] >= '1990', 'yearOfRelease'].astype(int)
ax = (sr.value_counts().sort_index()
        .plot.bar(title='number of movies by year of release',
                  xlabel='yearOfRelease', ylabel='numOfMovies',
                  rot=-90))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(500))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi,great bar chart there :) Is there a way i can just show 1990,1992,1994 and other even number years on the x-axis?

Comment: Thanks alot,Corralien! I am not sure when i try x = pandasDF[pandasDF['yearOfRelease'] >= '1990','yearOfRelease'].astype(int), i am getting type error:'(0 'yearOfRelease')' is an invalid key

Comment: No problem,i am great you offered to guide me :) @Corralien

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the guideline for 500,1000,1500,2500 in the expected bar plot picture shown above?